# How can I activate Multiplayer on my kids account in Minecraft on Windows on a PC?

Tags: user-accounts, minecraft, parental-controls, microsoft

I'm having a "Family Group" in a microsoft account: My kid and me.

She's trying to play Minecraft but it says: `Multiplayer is disabled. Please check your Microsoft account settings.`

[image: Minecraft in multplayer-disabled mode]

I've googled it and the official minecraft documentation [here](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4408968616077-How-to-Manage-Parental-Consent-Family-Settings-and-Realms-Multiplayer-Access-for-a-Child-Account#h_01FF8W5Q0CDHH1CE3XMNWTGF6D) says to go to the microsoft account and `Select Manage Minecraft under Content restrictions`.

[image: Official Minecraft documentation]

Nevertheless there's no such menu or block "Content Restrictions" in my kid's account when managed from my parent's account. The most similar place is "Content filters / Apps and Games" here:

[image: Microsoft account menu]

And there's no "Manage Minecraft" there.

There are many posts telling "just change the age and tell the kid is over 18". Of course that's **not** what I want. Many years still to go before she is 18.

## Question

How do I enable "multipleyer" for Minecraft for my kid?

Comment: This [link](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/4408968616077-How-to-Manage-Parental-Consent-Family-Settings-and-Realms-Multiplayer-Access-for-a-Child-Account) might help.

Comment: It appears [this](https://www.xbox.com/en-US/apps/family-settings-app) application is required to accomplish your task

Comment: @harrymc your link is the link I already posted in the question. We already did the steps there.

Comment: @Ramhound is that application managing only XBox games? Or also games running on the PC? We are running minecraft in Win11 as can be seen in the first image (says "java edition").

Comment: @XaviMontero - I have no idea, I just know, it will help configure your child’s Microsoft Account

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Turns out that the updated settings on the Xbox account as mentioned already (**You can play with people outside of Xbox Live**, **You can create and join clubs**, and **You can join multiplayer games**) didn't take effect even after a computer restart.

Solved by going into the Minecraft Launcher on my son’s computer under his account and signing out. (By clicking the profile name in the upper left corner). After signing in again it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I had to create an admin account for myself on my child's computer and make their account standard. This may not be your trouble however, since on your screenshot, I do not see the banner I had at the top indicating my child had admin rights on the computer, and there was a **Fix It** button with instructions on how to do so.

Furthermore, if Minecraft Launcher is not in the list of games exceptions, and the age restriction setting is set below Minecraft's recommended age of 10+, it could be blocking them. When I fired up Minecraft on my child's PC, it prompted me to send a request to the parent account to grant access as my child's setting is for 5 year old content without specific permission. You might want to try temporarily setting the age to 10 years to see if that fixes it. I signed them out and back in to the game launcher to pick up the updated settings.

I came back here to answer this because I came across it looking for the answer myself. I think the option of **Manage Minecraft** is in a parental management mobile app for mobile so you wouldn't find it on PC. I hope this helps someone out there!

Edit: I forgot that I also went into [Xbox account](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1129293843196555356/1187808529403367485/pyrite-pyrites-mineral-sulfide-56030.jpg?ex=65983be5&is=6585c6e5&hm=ba2a256a2c29899e1725c06bb93d1d3b2c1d634bf0f53fd72cb6bdf7c9bb11b0&=&format=webp), clicked on my child's profile, **Windows 10 Online Safety**, and enabled **You can play with people outside of Xbox Live**, **You can create and join clubs**, and **You can join multiplayer games**.